# How to add new content to a record using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a text file containing several records like:

```
 aaaaa
 bbbbb
 ccccc
```

I want to add a string (ex. "record:") in front of each record, so each of them will be like:

```
 record:aaaaa
 record:bbbbb
 record:ccccc
```

I have the code that reads this text file and creates a RDD for this file:

```
 val aRdd = sc.textFile("/tmp/myFile")
```

How do I add the string to each record in this RDD using Spark?  Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `RDD.map`:

```
val rddWithRecord = sc.textFile("/tmp/myFile").map(currentWord => s"record:$currentWord")
rddWithRecord.print()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply